# How do you investigate an Apache webserver that's not serving a Wordpress website you've just deployed?

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress

I am getting:

```
Apache 2 Test Pagepowered by CentOS
```

So, the Wordpress page isn't being served by Apache, but I don't know why. I am using CENTOS 6, and I just used a puppet config to deploy it, so I am wondering why it's not working. I used the same configs before and it didn't work and my colleague did something to fix it, but he didn't share me the details. I did sudo service httpd start, but I am thinking maybe there's another Apache library that was used and it messed up the page being served. I am also thinking there's a config for telling where the wordpress folder is inside Apache, but it wasn't properly configured. How do I check what apache installations there are on my machine and how do I check why it's not serving the Wordpress website?

Comment: I guess it's not configured to point to Wordpress folder. Check the apache config.

Comment: Apache 2.2 EOL in 2017. https://httpd.apache.org/#apache-httpd-22-end-of-life-2018-01-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for configuration in:
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`
What port it's running on 443 or 80?
you may check what command starts up apache, in example to check port 80:

```
ps -ef $(sudo lsof -i :80 | tail -1 | cut -d " " -f2)
```

Comment: Hmm, the directory doesn't exist. Apache is version 2.2.15 (Unix). I see a folder httpd, but it doesn't have the folder sites-enabled.

Comment: @haher provide the ourput of the command I posted above. it would show you where to look for the configuration file. e.g. /etc/httpd

Comment: Apache 2.2? Really? That branch ends its life in 2017! And you are not using the final version. `The final release 2.2.34 was published in July 2017, and no further evaluation of bug reports or security risks will be considered or published for 2.2.x releases.` https://httpd.apache.org/#apache-httpd-22-end-of-life-2018-01-01

Answer (score 0):

Look at your httpd.conf and see where you DocumentRoot points. That's where your web files should go.

Also make sure the permissions on those directories are correct or apache will not be able to get there.